# React-navigation call function on screen change

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I need to acquire data from the server to load user set settings when the user changes screen. It is done by a function in the class. I have tried:

```
componentWillMount(){
  console.log("Sent to function");
  this.onSaveCats('initialize');
}
```

What does not post anything to console log. I have not found a good solution for triggering a function when a new screen is changed. Is there something I am missing?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^20.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.47.0",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  }
```

Comment: tabBarOnPress() from the `TabNavigator` component can be used https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab.

Comment: I think you're on right way, but what about the screens? Is it seperate classes? You need to use that approach in every of this class

Answer (score 1):

In react navigation, we can subscribe to listeners and add corresponding callbacks.
The four events that we can subscribe to listeners on are:
willFocus, willBlur, didFocus and didBlur.

Usage in this case:

```
    export default class AnyScreen extends Component{
     constructor(props){
       super(props);
       const didBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
       'didBlur',
       payload => {
             console.debug('didBlur', payload);
       });
      }
    }
```

You can add similar subscription for didFocus as well by substituting 'didBlur' to any of the other options.

Once you're done listening, you can even remove the listener subscription:

```
didBlurSubscription.remove();
```

Hope this helps!